# Installing VS 2013 Pro over 2013 Web Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 Web Exppress installed on my PC.
The installation was plain, Default and no other stuff was installed by now.

Now I have a MSDN-Subscription and want to "updgrade" to Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

What is the best way?

1) Deinstalling VS 2013 Web Express and Install VS 2013 Pro

2) Just install VS 2013 Pro over VS 2013 Web Express

If I understand it right, I don´t need Web Express when I use Pro, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just go with option 2, it's a supported scenario.  However, you are correct that you'll no longer need Express, as Pro contains all the same features and more.

Note that if you've installed VS Updates for Express, you'll need to install the same VS Updates for Pro, or else some things might not work.

Comment: With Option 2, is Web Express then still present on my System or is it replaced? And no: I don´t have installed any updates.

Comment: It's still present, and you can launch either one.  But they share a significant number of their DLLs which is why having different update versions can break one or the other.

Comment: OK. In this case - and because I don´t need Web Express any more - I prefer to deinstall Express before installing Pro...